# Issue with eclipse; a java null error that I cannot solve

Tags: java, android, api, nullpointerexception, android-manifest

Okay so here's the jiff of it, I was changing the android API in the Android Manifest and the Android Manifest from the "bin" folder. I changed the API from 10 to 12 manually by removing the 0 and adding a 2. Now, when I go to save the project its giving me this error found in the image:

[image: java.lang.NullPointerException]

This is incredibly and extremely annoying not being able to find the problem. Yes, I am aware that there are other questions with this matter but I can't find anything that is useful/fixing my problem so I'm asking for help here. If anyone could help me fix my problem that would be beyond awesome! Also, if needed I can put some code. Something to take note is that there aren't any errors coming up in the LogCat but just this annoying pop-up.

Comment: Have you tried Project > Clean?

Comment: Have you done a clean/build?